# Parsing DateTime Go Gin

Tags: go, datetime, parsing, go-gin

I have problem when time.Time is parsed by gin.

I'am sending:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/search/?from=2023-08-25T17:00:00+03:00'
```

And my function and struct is:

```
type Filters struct {
    From   time.Time `form:"from" binding:"required,gte" time_format:"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" json:"from"`
}

func Search(c *gin.Context) {
    t := time.Now()
    filters := Filters{}

    if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&filters, binding.Query); err != nil {
        log.Infof("Filter parameter error => %s", err.Error())
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
// More code
}
```

The error message indicates that there's an issue with parsing the time zone part of the input, but I do not understand why.

```
{
    "error": "parsing time \"2023-08-25T17:00:00 03:00\" as \"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\": cannot parse \" 03:00\" as \"Z07:00\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stemmed from the URL encoding. The plus sign (+) was being lost during the encoding process, causing it to be transformed into a space character. Consequently, the parser was unable to recognize this format and rejected it.